# Material-UI dynamic Stepper component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to display a dynamic [Material-UI Stepper Component](https://material-ui.com/components/steppers/) when the user clicks on `ADD`, this stepper component should add to the UI. 
I am able to add stepper components dynamically, but the problem is when clicking on `NEXT`, `BACK`, or `SKIP` all added stepper components on the screen move accordingly.

For example, if I have three stepper components on-screen. When I click the `NEXT` button on any one of those components, all three components move next.

I am not sure how can I manage the `useState` of Material-UI stepper component.

```js
form.values.profile.map((x, idx) => {
  //Stepper Component rendering
})
```

Comment: Hey can you give a codesandbox link with minimal reproducable example?

Answer (score 0):

In order to have each of your Stepper components work separately, you can maintain separate `activeStep` value for each of the Stepper component.

**Like this:**

```js
export default function App() {
  const [steppers, setSteppers] = useState([{ activeStep: 0 }]);

  const addForm = () => {
    setSteppers(steppers.concat({ activeStep: 0 }));
  };

  const updateActiveStep = (index, count) => {
    setSteppers(prev =>
      prev.map((stepper, i) => {
        if (i === index) {
          return { ...stepper, activeStep: stepper.activeStep + count };
        }

        return stepper;
      })
    );
  };

  const handleReset = index => {
    setSteppers(prev =>
      prev.map((stepper, i) => {
        if (i === index) {
          return { ...stepper, activeStep: 0 };
        }
        return stepper;
      })
    );
  };

  console.log("stepper", steppers);
  const stepperForms = steppers.map((stepper, index) => (
    <MyStepper
      activeStep={stepper.activeStep}
      handleReset={() => handleReset(index)}
      setActiveStep={count => updateActiveStep(index, count)}
    />
  ));
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={addForm}>add form</button>
      {stepperForms}
    </>
  );
}
```

**Working dynamic-multistep-form implementation is here**:

https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-bhabha-i5wr2?file=/src/Stepper.js

**Also alternately**, you can maintain the activeStep with in the Stepper component so that the each instance of the Stepper is using its own active step value.

Comment: Thank you @gdh, but I am using `FieldArray` Component of `Formik` to add stepper. So when user click on `ADD` I am pushing stepper into array as shown into question. How can maintain activeState in such array or how can I use `steppers.map(..)` in that array

Comment: How we can implement remove. I have `REMOVE` button on each steppe. I want to remove it on click.

Comment: I have couple of TextField on my each stepper screen, when I move `NEXT` and again come `BACK` I am loosing state of previous state I mean I am loosing data entered into `TextField`, How can I keep state of each state (on `BACK` or `NEXT`)